# multinomial logistic regression with different formulae for different outcomes

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial

I am attempting to use a multinomial logistic regression model in which the formulae, or linear predictor, differs for one of the three outcomes.

Here is an example data set.  Sorry the code to create the data set is a little long:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
  obs  cov  cov2 n.a  n.b  n.c
    1   -7   49   40   60    0
    2   -6   36   40   60    0
    3   -5   25   40   60    0
    4   -4   16   40   60    0
    5   -3    9   40   59    1
    6   -2    4   40   57    3
    7   -1    1   40   47   13
    8    0    0   40   27   33
    9    1    1   40    9   51
   10    2    4   40    2   58
   11    3    9   40    1   59
   12    4   16   40    0   60
   13    5   25   40    0   60
   14    6   36   40    0   60
   15    7   49   40    0   60
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# duplicate rows
n.times <- my.data$n.a
data.a  <- my.data[rep(seq_len(nrow(my.data)), n.times),]
data.a$stage <- 'a'
n.times <- my.data$n.b
data.b  <- my.data[rep(seq_len(nrow(my.data)), n.times),]
data.b$stage <- 'b'
n.times <- my.data$n.c
data.c  <- my.data[rep(seq_len(nrow(my.data)), n.times),]
data.c$stage <- 'c'

# combine data sets
my.data <- rbind(data.a, data.b)
my.data <- rbind(my.data, data.c)

my.data <- my.data[order(my.data$cov, my.data$stage),]
head(my.data)
dim(my.data)
```

Here is code to create a model with the `nnet` package and the `mlogit` package:
In this model stage `b` and `c` are modeled with the same formula (an intercept, `cov` and `cov2`).  Stage `a` is the reference.  The two packages return very similar estimates.

```
# first with package nnet

library(nnet)

my.data$stage  <- as.factor(my.data$stage)
my.data$stage2 <- relevel(my.data$stage, ref = "a")
model1 <- multinom(stage2 ~ cov + cov2, data = my.data)
summary(model1)

#
# Call:
# multinom(formula = stage2 ~ cov + cov2, data = my.data)
#
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)        cov       cov2
# b  -0.7180498 -0.6390276 -0.0735323
# c  -0.5639989  0.5903990 -0.0701099
#
# Std. Errors:
#   (Intercept)        cov        cov2
# b   0.1191425 0.06643554 0.010191801
# c   0.1109950 0.05976451 0.009468451
#
# Residual Deviance: 2301.073 
# AIC: 2313.073 
#

fitted(model1)[1:10,]

# now with package mlogit 

library(mlogit)

my.datad <- my.data

my.datad <- my.data[,c('stage', 'cov', 'cov2')]
rownames(my.datad) <- NULL
head(my.datad)

my.datae <- mlogit.data(my.datad, shape = "wide", choice = "stage")
head(my.datae)

summary(mlogit(stage ~ 0 | cov + cov2, data = my.datae))

#
# Call:
# mlogit(formula = stage ~ 0 | cov + cov2, data = my.datae, method = "nr", 
#     print.level = 0)
#
# Frequencies of alternatives:
#       a       b       c 
# 0.40000 0.29467 0.30533 
#
# nr method
# 8 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
# g'(-H)^-1g = 8.63E-06 
# successive function values within tolerance limits 
#
# Coefficients :
#                 Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
# b:(intercept) -0.7189757  0.1192246 -6.0304 1.635e-09 ***
# c:(intercept) -0.5634641  0.1109489 -5.0786 3.802e-07 ***
# b:cov         -0.6398978  0.0665175 -9.6200 < 2.2e-16 ***
# c:cov          0.5898187  0.0597128  9.8776 < 2.2e-16 ***
# b:cov2        -0.0736489  0.0102012 -7.2197 5.211e-13 ***
# c:cov2        -0.0700294  0.0094624 -7.4008 1.352e-13 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
# Log-Likelihood: -1150.5
# McFadden R^2:  0.29554 
# Likelihood ratio test : chisq = 965.34 (p.value = < 2.22e-16)
#
```

However, what I want to do is use stage `b` as the reference, model stage `c` as a function of an intercept, `cov` and `cov2` as above, **but model stage `a` simply as a function of an intercept**.  Note that in the data set the covariates do not effect the number of trials that end in stage `a`: 40 trials end in stage `a` regardless of the value of the covariates.

Is such a model possible?  I believe it is, but I cannot figure out how to do it with either of these packages.  I have tried using various indicator variables to remove the covariates from the formula for stage `a` but coefficients are always estimated anyway and the standard errors become huge.  Sometimes the point estimates also become very large also.

I am asking a related question on `Cross Validated`, but I consider this present question to be primarily about programming.  Here is a link to my related question on Cross Validated, if interested:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183427/modeling-probability-with-the-multinomial-logit-link/184004#184004

Thank you for any advice.

**EDIT Nov 30, 2015**

I have now obtained estimates from two other software programs.  These estimates are possible target values I would like to see from `R`.  Although, I suspect better estimates eventually might be possible.

Estimates from one application:

```
Parameter       Beta           SE    Lower 95%CI  Upper 95%CI
state a: B0   0.305620     0.062682     0.182764     0.428476
state c: B0  -0.094760     0.113606    -0.317428     0.127908
state c: B1   0.750266     0.038993     0.673841     0.826692
state d: B2  -0.085494     0.012216    -0.109437    -0.061551
```

Estimates from a second application:

```
Parameter       Beta           SE      Lower 95%CI   Upper 95%CI
state a: B0   0.3056197    0.0626826    0.1827618    0.4284777
state c: B0  -0.0947603    0.1124746   -0.3152105    0.1256900
state c: B1   0.7502663    0.0601626    0.6323476    0.8681850     
state c: B2  -0.0854941    0.0095836   -0.1042780   -0.0667102
```

**EDIT TWO Nov 30, 2015**

If I model both states `a` and `c` with both covariates I get the following from both `R` packages and from two other software applications:

```
#
# model data with stage 'b' as reference
#
# model stage 'a' as function of intercept, cov and cov2
# model stage 'c' as function of intercept, cov and cov2
#
# model: a(cov, cov2) c(cov1, cov2)
#
# Parameter        Beta       SE      95%CI Lower     95%CI Upper
#
#    1:        0.1555116   0.1390947  -0.1171141      0.4281373     
#    2:        0.7189753   0.1192245   0.4852953      0.9526554     
#    3:        1.2297161   0.0853667   1.0623974      1.3970347     
#    4:        0.0036194   0.0147607  -0.0253116      0.0325505     
#    5:        0.6398974   0.0665175   0.5095231      0.7702717     
#    6:        0.0736488   0.0102012   0.0536545      0.0936431     
#

library(nnet)
my.data2 <- my.data

my.data2$stage  <- as.factor(my.data2$stage)
my.data2$stage2 <- relevel(my.data2$stage, ref = "b")

model1.nnet <- multinom(stage2 ~ cov + cov2, data = my.data2)
summary(model1.nnet)

# Call:
# multinom(formula = stage2 ~ cov + cov2, data = my.data2)
#
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)       cov        cov2
# a   0.7189754 0.6398974 0.073648810
# c   0.1555120 1.2297159 0.003619449
#
# Std. Errors:
#   (Intercept)        cov       cov2
# a   0.1192246 0.06651748 0.01020116
# c   0.1390947 0.08536677 0.01476072
#
# Residual Deviance: 2301.073 
# AIC: 2313.073 

library(mlogit)
my.data2b <- my.data2[,c('stage', 'cov', 'cov2')]
rownames(my.data2b) <- NULL
head(my.data2b)

my.data2.mlogit <- mlogit.data(my.data2b, shape = "wide", choice = "stage")
head(my.data2.mlogit)

summary(mlogit(stage ~ 0 | cov + cov2, data = my.data2.mlogit, reflevel = "b"))

# Coefficients :
#               Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
# a:(intercept) 0.7189757  0.1192246  6.0304 1.635e-09 ***
# c:(intercept) 0.1555116  0.1390948  1.1180    0.2636    
# a:cov         0.6398978  0.0665175  9.6200 < 2.2e-16 ***
# c:cov         1.2297166  0.0853668 14.4051 < 2.2e-16 ***
# a:cov2        0.0736489  0.0102012  7.2197 5.211e-13 ***
# c:cov2        0.0036195  0.0147607  0.2452    0.8063    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
```

However, if I try to model state `a` just with an intercept I still am not getting similar estimates with either `R` package that I get with the two other applications:

```
#
# model data with stage 'b' as reference
#
# model stage 'a' as function of intercept only
# model stage 'c' as function of intercept, cov and cov2
#
#  Parameter        Beta           SE     95%CI Lower  95%CI Upper
#
#  stage a: B0    0.305620     0.062682     0.182764     0.428476
#  state c: B0   -0.094760     0.113606    -0.317428     0.127908
#  state c: B1    0.750266     0.038993     0.673841     0.826692
#  state c: B2   -0.085494     0.012216    -0.109437    -0.061551
#

library(nnet)

my.data3 <- my.data

my.data3$stage  <- as.factor(my.data3$stage)
my.data3$stage2 <- relevel(my.data3$stage, ref = "b")

my.data3$cov  <- ifelse(my.data3$stage == 'a', 0, my.data3$cov )
my.data3$cov2 <- ifelse(my.data3$stage == 'a', 0, my.data3$cov2)

model2.nnet <- multinom(stage2 ~ cov + cov2, data = my.data3)
summary(model2.nnet)

#     Call:
# multinom(formula = stage2 ~ cov + cov2, data = my.data3)
#
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)       cov         cov2
# a   3.1129805 0.5936333 -13.85909619
# c   0.2221975 1.5220859  -0.01343098
#
# Std. Errors:
#   (Intercept)        cov        cov2
# a   0.1694357 33.9858262 33.98601992
# c   0.1834233  0.1339483  0.06296883
#
# Residual Deviance: 661.0351 
# AIC: 673.0351 

library(mlogit)

my.data3b <- my.data3[,c('stage', 'cov', 'cov2')]
rownames(my.data3b) <- NULL
head(my.data3b)

my.data3.mlogit <- mlogit.data(my.data3b, shape = "wide", choice = "stage")
head(my.data3.mlogit)

summary(mlogit(stage ~ 0 | cov + cov2, data = my.data3.mlogit, reflevel = "b"))

# Coefficients :
#                 Estimate  Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)    
# a:(intercept)    3.112970    0.169436 18.3726   <2e-16 ***
# c:(intercept)    0.222162    0.183426  1.2112   0.2258    
# a:cov            0.829259 2276.499314  0.0004   0.9997    
# c:cov            1.522129    0.133954 11.3631   <2e-16 ***
# a:cov2         -22.295201 2276.499317 -0.0098   0.9922    
# c:cov2          -0.013431    0.062973 -0.2133   0.8311    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
```

Comment: Well you could cheat and make `cov` and `cov2` be zero whenever the outcome is `a` in the training set.

Comment: @slushy  Thank you for the suggestion.  That is one of the approaches I attempted before posting.  It still seemed to return parameter estimates for the covariates anyway and SE's became huge.  Is that what you found?  I can take another look at that approach and see whether I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a good approach to this problem would be to break it down into two models. 
You need the probability that stage = a independent of the covariates. Then you want to know, given that  stage != a, the probability stage = b or c dependent on the covariates.

```
#pr(stage=a)
my.data$stageA.BC = my.data$stage=="a"
glm(my.data$stageA.BC ~ 1,family=binomial)



#pr(stage=c|cov,cov2,stage!= a)
my.data.BC = my.data[my.data$stageA.BC==0,]
my.data.BC = relevel(my.data.BC$stage,ref="b")
glm(stage ~cov + cov2, data=my.data.BC,family=binomial)
```

As pr(stage = b OR c) = 1 - pr(stage=a), you would then have:

```
pr(stage = a) 

pr(stage = b) = (1 - pr(stage = a)) * pr(stage=b|cov,cov2,stage!= a)

pr(stage = c) = (1 - pr(stage = a)) * pr(stage=c|cov,cov2,stage!= a)
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea.  I will think about it.  However, my two main concerns are 1.) whether `pr(a) + pr(b) + pr(c)` might exceed one with this approach and 2) whether this approach would work with a substantially more complex model that I am using here to illustrate the problem I am having with the `mlogit` and `nnet` packages.

Comment: pr(a) + pr(b) + pr(c) should equal 1 as (1 - pr(stage = a)) * pr(stage=b|cov,cov2,stage!= a) + (1 - pr(stage = a)) * (1-pr(stage=b|cov,cov2,stage!= a)) = 1- pr(stage = a). The approach in my answer might get tricky with more complex models, but I believe in theory what you're looking for is a Hierarchical Logit Model. There are packages for these models in r, although I can't comment on their use.

Answer (score 0):

Below is `R` code that estimates parameters using `optim` when stages `a` and `c` are each related to both covariates `cov` and `cov2` and when stage `a` is only modeled with an intercept.

**Given that I have been able to model stage `a` with just an intercept three different ways now, I am unclear why I cannot obtain the same estimates with the `mlogit` or `nnet` `R` packages.**

First create the data set as before:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
  obs  cov  cov2 n.a  n.b  n.c
    1   -7   49   40   60    0
    2   -6   36   40   60    0
    3   -5   25   40   60    0
    4   -4   16   40   60    0
    5   -3    9   40   59    1
    6   -2    4   40   57    3
    7   -1    1   40   47   13
    8    0    0   40   27   33
    9    1    1   40    9   51
   10    2    4   40    2   58
   11    3    9   40    1   59
   12    4   16   40    0   60
   13    5   25   40    0   60
   14    6   36   40    0   60
   15    7   49   40    0   60
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# duplicate rows
n.times.a <- my.data$n.a
data.a  <- my.data[rep(seq_len(nrow(my.data)), n.times.a),]
data.a$stage <- 'a'
n.times.b <- my.data$n.b
data.b  <- my.data[rep(seq_len(nrow(my.data)), n.times.b),]
data.b$stage <- 'b'
n.times.c <- my.data$n.c
data.c  <- my.data[rep(seq_len(nrow(my.data)), n.times.c),]
data.c$stage <- 'c'

# combine data sets
my.data <- rbind(data.a, data.b)
my.data <- rbind(my.data, data.c)

my.data <- my.data[order(my.data$cov, my.data$stage),]

# Here are a few additional lines to prepare the data set for my `optim` functions.

cov  <- my.data$cov
cov2 <- my.data$cov2

n.a  <- ifelse(my.data$stage == 'a', 1, 0)
n.b  <- ifelse(my.data$stage == 'b', 1, 0)
n.c  <- ifelse(my.data$stage == 'c', 1, 0)
```

Here is `optim` code for multinomial logistic regression that returns the same estimates as the `mlogit` and `nnet` packages and two other software applications (i.e., stages `a` and `c` are each modeled with an intercept, and `cov1` and `cov2` effects):

```
my.function <- function(betas, cov, cov2, n.a, n.b, n.c){

     b0a = betas[1]
     b1a = betas[2]
     b2a = betas[3]
     b0c = betas[4]
     b1c = betas[5]
     b2c = betas[6]

     n = nrow(my.data)

     llh = 0

     for(i in 1:n){

          y <- (

                (n.b[i] * (1 - exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) / 
                          (1 + exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i]))    - 
                               exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i]) / 
                          (1 + exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) )) +

                (n.c[i] * (    exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i]) / 
                          (1 + exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) )) +

                (n.a[i] * (    exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) / 
                          (1 + exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) ))

               )

          y <- log(y)

          y <- ifelse(is.na(y), 0.0000000001, y)

          llh = llh + y

     }

     -1 * llh

}

Nstar <- optim(c(0,0,0,0,0,0), my.function, cov = cov, cov2 = cov2, n.a = n.a, n.b = n.b, n.c = n.c, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)
Nstar$par

# [1] 0.718951850 0.639832930 0.073637858 0.155471765 1.229635652 0.003612455
```

Here is the `optim` code for multinomial logistic regression when stage `c` is modeled with an intercept, and `cov1` and `cov2` effects, but stage `a` is only modeled with an intercept.  The estimates returned match the estimates I obtained with two other software applications, but not with those obtained with the `mlogit` or `nnet` packages in `R`:

```
my.other.function <- function(betas, cov, cov2, n.a, n.b, n.c){

     b0a = betas[1]
     b0c = betas[2]
     b1c = betas[3]
     b2c = betas[4]

     n = nrow(my.data)

     llh = 0

     for(i in 1:n){

          y <- (

                (n.b[i] * (1 - exp(b0a                               ) / (1 + exp(b0a) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) - 
                               exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i]) / (1 + exp(b0a) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) )) +

                (n.c[i] * (    exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i]) / (1 + exp(b0a) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) )) +

                (n.a[i] * (    exp(b0a                               ) / (1 + exp(b0a) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) ))


               )

          y <- log(y)

          y <- ifelse(is.na(y), 0.0000000001, y)

          llh = llh + y

     }

     -1 * llh

}

Nstar <- optim(c(0,0,0,0), my.other.function, cov = cov, cov2 = cov2, n.a = n.a, n.b = n.b, n.c = n.c, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)
Nstar$par

# [1]  0.30561794 -0.09473753  0.75021769 -0.08548674
```

Perhaps there is something fundamentally wrong with the approach I am taking with `optim` that explains why the `mlogit` and `nnet` packages will not allow creation of this model structure?  Or perhaps I simply have not yet figured out the correct syntax to use with the `mlogit` and `nnet` packages?

I might need to extract and study the source code that the `mlogit` and `nnet` packages are using to see whether I can modify it, or at least figure out what it is doing when I try to model stage `a` with just an intercept.

If I figure out how to model stage `a` with just an intercept using the `mlogit` or `nnet` (or the `mnlogit`) `R` packages then I will post an update.

**EDIT: December 7, 2015**

I now have been able to use `optim` to reproduce the estimates produced by `mlogit`.  The `R` code is below.  The conclusion is that the three approaches I have used until now have involved me modifying the design matrix to remove covariates from stage `a`.  Simply setting data for covariates to `0` does not remove those covariates from the design matrix.

```
cov  <- ifelse(my.data$stage == 'a', 0, cov )
cov2 <- ifelse(my.data$stage == 'a', 0, cov2)

my.third.function <- function(betas, cov, cov2, n.a, n.b, n.c){

     b0a = betas[1]
     b1a = betas[2]
     b2a = betas[3]
     b0c = betas[4]
     b1c = betas[5]
     b2c = betas[6]

     n = nrow(my.data)

     llh = 0

     for(i in 1:n){

          y <- (

                (n.b[i] * (1 - exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) / 
                          (1 + exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i]))    - 
                               exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i]) / 
                          (1 + exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) )) +

                (n.c[i] * (    exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i]) / 
                          (1 + exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) )) +

                (n.a[i] * (    exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) / 
                          (1 + exp(b0a + b1a * cov[i] + b2a * cov2[i]) + exp(b0c + b1c * cov[i] + b2c * cov2[i])) ))

               )

#         y <- ifelse(is.na(y) | y <= 0, 0.0000000001, y)

          y <- log(y)

          llh = llh + y

     }

     -1 * llh

}

model3 <- optim(c(0,0,0,0,0,0), my.third.function, cov = cov, cov2 = cov2, n.a = n.a, n.b = n.b, n.c = n.c, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)
model3$par

#
# [1]   3.11296505   0.61033815 -13.89223292   0.22214130   1.52209746  -0.01344045
#
```

I have also dissected the source code for the `mlogit` package.  So far I have been able to remove covariates from the design matrix in that source code, but simply doing that does not return the correct estimates.  My change in the design matrix must be causing errors later in the source code.

I will post an update if I am able to modify the rest of the source code to return correct estimates or if I am able to figure out the correct syntax for removing the covariates in the `mlogit` statement in my original post.